# Collect .txt and .log files using find

Tags: unix, shell, find

I currently have this script to compress log files:

```
find . -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file
```

Currently finds and compress all the *.log files.  I would like to modify it to include also all the ".txt" files but I don't know how, this should be fairly simple right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -type f \( -name "*.log" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec tar zcf "$file" {} +`

Alternatively:

`find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(txt\|log\)$" -exec tar zcf "$file" {} +`

No need for `xargs` if your version of `find` is POSIX compliant and can have it's `-exec` command terminated with a `+` (most can)

Comment: I got: `find: missing argument to `-exec'` I think I did that, but I needed to preserver the directory structure.

Comment: @OscarRyz I forgot to add the `$file` variable (fixed) but from your output it looks like you put the `{}` before "$file" rather than after.  The directory structure *will* be preserved

Comment: The first version only collect .txt files, the 2nd work though. Could you leave the second only?

Comment: @Oscar fixed it =). You need to group the two `-name` options to enforce order of precedence.

Comment: I'm still getting the missing argument :( . Anyway, I manage to modify it to this: `find . -regex '.*\.\(log\|txt\)'  -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file`

Comment: @Oscar looks like your version of `find` has not been updated to the 2004 POSIX spec which added the `+` terminator to `-exec`. In that case, your use of `xargs -0` with `-print0` is the correct alternative.  Also, I would add the `-type f` flag so you don't match on symlinks or sockets or block/character devices by accident.